# Does exsist an open source Air Gesture recognition for Android

Tags: android, gesture-recognition

i'm looking for an Air Gesture recognition library for Android.
The perfect thing should be an open source library or something that the community is developing and that i can use for free and help them to develop.
Unfortunately i didn't found anything ready. 
Do you know something like it?
I found only nanogest(http://www.nanocritical.com/nanogest/) but i asked them the library but without answer.
Do you know where i can find something like it?
Samsung did it on S4, so somewhere the libraries are present :)
Hope you can help me!
Thank you
R

Comment: how about using a leap motion device, https://developer.leapmotion.com/

Comment: heres samsung sdk location http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-mobile-sdk#gesture